# What could be the reason for using line frequency toroidal transformers at the input of a power supply board (with PFC)?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, reverse-engineering, power-factor-correction

During the teardown of a power supply board, we found a bulky toroidal transformer (similar to image below) at the ac input line (voltage 115V AC). The secondary of transformer is subsequently connected to rectifier and PFC circuits.

What could be the reason for including a line frequency transformer as we generally don't prefer line frequency magnetic components in  a power supply board?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it was a transformer, and not a common-mode choke?

Comment: Iam not sure. It had 4 windings. 2 were connected to AC inlet and 2 were connected to rectifier input. Is there any way to verify whether it is a transformer or CMC without powering the board?

Comment: Could be useful to minimize leakage currents.  You often see AC toroidal transformers in patient-attached medical equipment.

Comment: It could be for isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this is a large common-mode choke.  Only because of the bare area and small number of turns visible in the photo. (In general, power transformers have many overlapping windings to maximize power density - common-mode chokes do not.)

It could be a transformer, CMC, or hybrid with a "sense" winding which some other part of the supply samples to see how much noise is being emitted back into the AC mains.  Never seen this myself, but sounds plausible for a high-performance / lab / medical-grade supply.

> Is there any way to verify whether it is a transformer or CMC without powering the board?

Well, checking AC voltages with power applied might be easiest.  But if you have access to the windings (such as removable spade connectors), measure Continuity and Ohms between all of them.  Then disconnect it and measure again.  Sketch and trace what you find to try making sense of it.  This could be many different winding configurations, perhaps something like one of these:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRR1Gz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Transformers are often custom-made.  If it has a part number on it, can try searching the web for that.

Failing that, if you have an LCR meter, you can compare the windings' inductances - chances are they are all nearly identical.  But if they are very different (meaning the windings have a different number of turns), that will *also* affect the transformation ratio.